# How do I calculate the mean of the same time series data several times with different time horizons given from a second data frame?

Tags: r

I have two data frames. One with relevant time horizons (in years) of observations and one with time series data of a contextual factor. The time horizons differ for every observation. I want to calculate the mean of the contextual factor time series data for every observation's time horizon. It would be best if the output would become a new column of the time horizon data frame.

So if these two dataframes are given:

```
            
           time_horizon <- data.frame(observation = c("A", "B", "C"), 
                                       start = c(2010, 2012, 2011), 
                                       end = c(2013, 2014, 2015)
                                       )
     
            data <- data.frame(Year = c(2010:2015), 
                               Value = c(26374, 21134, 21212, 21111, 21344, 22222)
                               )
```

I need something like this as a result:

```
        output <- data.frame(observation = c("A", "B", "C"), 
                                  start = c(2010, 2011, 2012), 
                                  end = c(2013, 2014, 2015),
                                  mean = c(22457.75, 21222.33, 21404.6)
        )
```

I have tried several combinations of a code like this.

```
            time_horizon$mean <- mean(
              data$Value[data$Year >= time_horizon[, "start"] & 
                     data$Year <= time_horizon[, "end"]
                     ]
              )
```

But obviously this only generates a column of equal values, so I guess `mean()` alone doesn't do the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `fuzzyjoin` :

```
library(dplyr)

fuzzyjoin::fuzzy_inner_join(time_horizon, data, 
                            by = c('start' = 'Year', 'end' = 'Year'), 
                            match_fun = c(`<=`, `>=`)) %>%
  group_by(observation, start, end) %>%
  summarise(mean = mean(Value)) -> result

result

#  observation start   end   mean
#  <chr>       <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
#1 A            2010  2013 22458.
#2 B            2012  2014 21222.
#3 C            2011  2015 21405.
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Much appreciated!